# Barchart two percentages per category in SAS

Tags: sas, bar-chart, percentage

I have two percentages per category (5 categories).
Now I would like to plot these ten percentages grouped by category.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So making assumption that you have data like

```
CATEGORY PCT1 PCT2
A        .5   .5
B        .3   .3
```

If so, then transpose the data:

```
proc transpose data=test out=test;
by category;
run;
```

You now have

```
CATEGORY _NAME_ COL1
A        PCT1   .5
A        PCT2   .5
...
```

Then plot with SGPLOT and VBARPARAM:

```
proc sgplot data=test;
vbarparm category=category response=col1 /group=_name_ groupdisplay=cluster;
run;
```

You get:
[image: Default Formatting]

Edit the labels etc to format as you need.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Just curious - I know sgplot is less code, but the GTL seems is now part of base SAS (unlike sgplot which is part of SAS/Graph) so why not provide chart examples using something that everyone has access to?

Comment: @RobertPenridge, `SGPLOT` is part of BASE, not GRAPH.  http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.2&docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=n0yjdd910dh59zn1toodgupaj4v9.htm&locale=en

Comment: Ahhh - good to know - thanks.  I think I may have been getting mixed up with `proc gchart`.  I guess the `sg` prefix should have clued me in.